# Is there a keyboard shortcut in OS X Mavericks for quick reply when an iMessage notification appears?

Tags: keyboard, macos, notifications

I found it not that efficient to move the mouse pointer over the notification and click on the *reply* button every time.

So I was wondering if there is a hotkey for quick reply instead of using the mouse or the trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

You could [assign a keyboard shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to click window 1 of process "Notification Center"
```

Comment: I've tried that using Keyboard Maestro. But it simply brings up the Message window to the front, rather than doing a quick reply after clicking on the reply button. Is there any script that can click on that button? Thanks!

Comment: And also, I've tried something like `tell application "System Events" to click button "Reply" of window 1 of process "Notification Center"` But it does not work. Because you have to move the mouse pointer over the notification, or the _reply_ button won't appear.

Comment: @ylorn I don't use Messages, but I thought clicking a notification would reply to the message. `click button "Reply" of window 1` might work if you changed the alert style from banners to alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script to do this using Yosemite's [JavaScript for Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html) and its Objective-C bridge.

```js
ObjC.import("CoreGraphics");
// Notification only detects hover when moving from outside its borders
// over it, so first go to (0, 0).
$.CGWarpMouseCursorPosition({x:0 , y:0});
mainDisplayWidth = $.CGDisplayPixelsWide($.CGMainDisplayID());
$.CGWarpMouseCursorPosition({x:mainDisplayWidth - 50, y:81});

Application("System Events")
    .processes["Notification Center"]
    .windows()[0]
    .buttons["Reply"]
    .click();
```

If you want to run this in a shell (e.g. Alfred doesn't support JavaScript yet), you can use this one-liner that executes the script via `osascript`:

```
echo 'ObjC.import("CoreGraphics"); $.CGWarpMouseCursorPosition({x:0 , y:0}); mainDisplayWidth = $.CGDisplayPixelsWide($.CGMainDisplayID()); $.CGWarpMouseCursorPosition({x:mainDisplayWidth - 50, y:81}); Application("System Events") .processes["Notification Center"] .windows()[0] .buttons["Reply"] .click(); ' | osascript -l JavaScript
```

You can assign this script to a shortcut using any automation tool. I'm using [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/), [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) works as well.

You'll have to [allow the automation tool you're using to control your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-lb/HT202866), otherwise the mouse will move, but the script can't click the 'Reply'. In my case, I added Alfred there.